# WPF Radcalender customization day template format

Tags: wpf, mvvm, calendar, telerik

I want to cretae wpf radcalender in my wpf mvvm application. I can't able to customize the calender day template. I want to this format.

I am using this code. But the text has been overwrite the date.

xmal:

```
<telerik:RadCalendar Margin="30" SelectableDateStart="2015-01-01" SelectableDateEnd="2015-01-31" >          
                <telerik:RadCalendar.DayTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="Test"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadCalendar.DayTemplate>            
        </telerik:RadCalendar>
```

Comment: give me a link to the screenshot and i will post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked with the RadCalendar within a Winrt app and here how i fixed that (with some help from the official Docs)

First add a new converter that will return the Date Label like that:

```
public class CellModelConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var cellModel = value as CalendarCellModel;                       
            return cellModel.Label;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

then in you Xaml add a textBlock to display the Cell Date using the previous converter :

```
<telerik:RadCalendar Margin="30" SelectableDateStart="2015-01-01" SelectableDateEnd="2015-01-31" >
            <telerik:RadCalendar.DayTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="Test"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CellModelConverter}}" FontSize="13.333" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="6,0,0,4" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadCalendar.DayTemplate>
        </telerik:RadCalendar>
```

and don't forget to add the Converter to the Static Resources:

```
<converters:CellModelConverter x:Key="CellModelConverter" />
```

**--EDIT 1**

the code above work fine in a Winrt application, for a WPF project you don't need a converter at all :

```
 <telerik:RadCalendar Margin="30" SelectableDateStart="2015-01-01" SelectableDateEnd="2015-01-31" >
            <telerik:RadCalendar.DayTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="Test"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="13.333" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="6,0,0,4" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadCalendar.DayTemplate>
        </telerik:RadCalendar>
```

**--EDIT 2**

the above code shows the "test" text in all the cells including WeekName, DayName ..., to fix that you can use either a Converter or a DataTrigger, here how to do it using a DataTrigger :

```
<telerik:RadCalendar Margin="30" SelectableDateStart="2015-01-01" SelectableDateEnd="2015-01-31" >
            <telerik:RadCalendar.DayTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="Test">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                               <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                   <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ButtonType,ElementName=tb}"
                       Value="Date">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                               </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CellModelConverter}}" FontSize="13.333" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="6,0,0,4" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:RadCalendar.DayTemplate>
        </telerik:RadCalendar>
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I am not able to use the Converter code because var cellModel = value as CalenderCellModel throw error.

Comment: Hi @Joseph, this code is working but the text not only displayed in the date column. Day header also text has coming. Eg day heading is ( SUN test, MON test, TUE test). Can you help me. The text need to show only in date column.